# With AngularJs ngRoute, how do I route to a component in a separate module than the root module?

Tags: angularjs

I have an application that uses AngularJs (v1.7.9). I have started the migration of the app towards Angular 10+. I have converted a few associated directive/controllers to components. So far so good. Then I moved these components into a separate module. The app still builds and runs, however when navigating to the routes for these components, the component doesn't show. Here are some psuedo code that matches my project, with most of the details spared for brevity.

```
// overview/index.js
export default angular.module('overview', []).name;

// componentA.js
(function() {
   const ComponentA = {
      selector: 'componentA',
      template: 'path/to/template.html',
      bindings: {},
      constrollerAs: 'ctrl',
      controller: function () {
         console.log('component A');
      }
   };

   angular.module('overview').component(ComponentA.selector ComponentA);
})();

// app.js
import Overview from './overview/index.js';

const app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','Overview'])
   .config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) => {

            $routeProvider.when(`/`, {
                template: '<componentA></componentA>'
            });

            ...
            // other routes that still work; controllers defined within app module
}])
...
```

I can't tell if I don't have the module syntax correct, or if it just can't find the component to use to render.

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: the error stemmed from "template: 'path...'; the fix was changing template to templateUrl

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Hiatt, I believe you would add to the app.js a reference to the `overview` component as a directive. This would be added after the definition of the `app` const:

```
app.directive('componentA', Overview)
```